# Search in String Array in android

Tags: android, string, search, message, contains

Hi i have below code and want to show a message using Toast if String "message" contains farsi character but even the String do not have farsi character the Toast Message while be show where is the problem in my code?
Thanks in advance!

```
int len=message.length();
                                final String [] chr={ "چ","ج","ح","خ","ه","ع","غ","ف","ق","ث","ص","ض",
                                                    "ش","س","ی","ب","ل","ا","ت","ن","م","ک","گ","ظ","ط","ز",
                                                    "ر","ذ","د","ئ","و","?","آ","ژ","پ","ء","،","ۀ","؛",
                                                    "ٌ","'ً","آ","ِ","ُ","َ","ة","ي","ؤ","إ","أ" };


                                  for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
                                  {

                                        for(int j=0;j<49;j++)
                                      {
                                          if(message.contains(chr[j]));
                                          {
                                              EnglishSms="false";  
                                              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), chr[j], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                             // break;
                                          }
                                      }
                                  }
```

Comment: why there is two for loops ? and what is length ? please elaborate your question

Comment: this for ("for(int i=0;i<len;i++)") is to repeat the cod from 0 to message lengh and this for("for(int j=0;j<49;j++)") is to compar each charcter with 49 farsi charracter.

Answer (score 2):

Remove semicolon from here

```
if(message.contains(chr[j]));
```

P.S: only this would do the trick

```
for(int j=0;j<49;j++) {
    if(message.contains(chr[j]))
    {
        EnglishSms="false";  
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), chr[j], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String message = "TheMessageToCheckWith";
final String [] chr={ "چ","ج","ح","خ","ه","ع","غ","ف","ق","ث","ص","ض",
        "ش","س","ی","ب","ل","ا","ت","ن","م","ک","گ","ظ","ط","ز",
        "ر","ذ","د","ئ","و","?","آ","ژ","پ","ء","،","ۀ","؛",
        "ٌ","'ً","آ","ِ","ُ","َ","ة","ي","ؤ","إ","أ" };

for(int i = 0; i < chr.length; i++) {
  if(message.contains(chr[i])) {
    //TODO: Show Toast
    //Break;
  }
}
```

Changed the code a little for you.